I can't get rhythmbox to display cover art after reinstalling rhythmbox-plugin-artdisplay ubuntu 24.04
dell optiplex 7020 with hdmi video and sound
ubuntu 24.04.1
rhythmbox 3.4.7
 I had the rhythmbox working with the artdisplay rhythmbox-plugin-artdisplay with

ubuntu 22.04. After the update to 24.04.1 the audio was poor to nonexistant. trying to regain a good audio I tried several of the suggestions to recover it. One of the suggestions was to remove any third party plugins. I removed the artdisplay using
"sudo apt-get remove rhythmbox-plugin-artdisplay". It didn't help so I tried reverting to earlier kernals and found one that restored my audio (Known and reported bug). Now that the audio is working again I tried to reinstall the plugin "sudo apt install thythmbox-plugin-artdisplay" it seemed to install smoothly, no errors found. The plugin appeared in the list and I checked it to enable it. Everything seemed ok the album art header in the properties menu was there and displayed the art in the property menu. However the window at the bottom left that should display the cover art remains blank. Any suggestions on how to get this back.
